# is there any way of embedding html into pygame

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pygame

So, I am trying to create a virtual assistant in `pygame`, but I could not find any way of adding my search results into the window, I was planning to web scrape all the html with `beatifulsoup` and put that html into `pygame`, but the problem is that I don't know any way of how one can embed html inside `pygame`, and to be clear, I am not talking about embedding `pygame` to html, but putting html inside a `pygame` window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do this directly in pygame. But you can use an external tool like [wkhtmltoimage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to render your HTML to an image and use that in pygame.

Here's a simple example using [imgkit](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/) (a python wrapper for wkhtmltoimage):

```
import pygame
import imgkit
from io import BytesIO

def main():
    config = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage=r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe')

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480))

    html = "<style type = 'text/css'> body { font-family: 'Arial' } </style><body><h1>Html rendering</h1><div><ul><li><em>using pygame</em></li><li><strong>using imgkit</strong></li></ul></div></body>"
    img = imgkit.from_string(html, False, config=config)
    surface = pygame.image.load(BytesIO(img)).subsurface((0,0,280,123))
    r = 0
    center = screen.get_rect().center
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                return

        screen.fill('white')
        tmp = pygame.transform.rotozoom(surface, r, 1)
        tmp_r = tmp.get_rect(center=center)
        screen.blit(tmp, tmp_r)
        r += 1
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]